# Does bash function create new instances of itself when called recursively?

Tags: bash, shell, recursion

I have a function that makes several calls to itself, but the it does seem to approach its terminating value. For example

```
function multi () {
    a = $1
    b = $2
    c = a + b
    if [[ a > 2 ]]
    then
        let "$a = $a -1"
        multi $a $b
    fi
}
```

When it calls multi - the new child function uses the old variables

Comment: How do you call this function?

Comment: What's the point of `c = a + b`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implicitly created variables are global to the current shell - thus, each recursion of your function will overwrite the same global variables.

**Declare your variables with `local` to make them local to the function (invocation).**

That said, there are **multiple problems with your function** (and if you're really using `bash`, your function shouldn't execute at all):

- Variable assignments must not have spaces around `=` (unless inside `((...))`)
- Arithmetic expressions such as `c = a + b` must be performed inside `((...))`
- Numeric comparisons with `>` must be performed inside `((...))` (alternatively, use `[[ ... ]]` with `-gt`, but there your variable references must be `$`-prefixed)
- As @Florin Stingaciu points out in his answer, you must not use the `$` prefix on the left side of the assignment passed to `let` - preferably, though, use `((...))` here also, as it simplifies things: `let "a = $a -1"` simply becomes `(( --a ))`

Generally, pasting your code at http://shellcheck.net would reveal these problems.

Here's a version that works:

```
function multi() {
    local a b c  # declare variables as _local_
    a=$1
    b=$2
    (( c = a + b ))
    if (( a > 2 ))
    then
      (( --a ))
      multi $a $b
    fi
}
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation of how local variables work. I wasn't worried about the correctness of the function.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have a couple of errors. Here's the working version:

```
function multi () {
  a=$1
  b=$2
  c=a+b
  if [[ $a -gt 2 ]]
  then
    let "a = $a -1"
    multi $a $b
  fi
}
```

You had

```
if [[ a > 2 ]]
```

When it should've been:

```
if [[ $a -gt 2 ]]
```

Also the let statement is wrong. It should be:

```
let "a = $a -1"
```

Comment: `[[ $a > 2 ]]` performs _lexical_ comparison; use `-gt` for numbers.

Comment: @mklement0 Fixed. I missed that one.